SHA256 Endianness problems
For a project, I wanted to implement SHA256 in C from scratch. However, the specification here mixes things up with little and big endianness and makes things unclear. I've coded the entire hashing process but I kept getting wrong results. After looking at my intermediate results, I've noticed there are significant problems with endianness (I used memory watch on CLion). I am working on a little endian machine.
Let us have an input like "abc". This input, according to the specification, should be then padded to get a 64 byte (512 bit) block. First, a 1 is appended, then zeroes until the last 64 bits, which represent the message length in bits (24). This 64 bit block should be in big endian according to the specification.
Here is the padded block in hexa, in little endian. The smaller address is on top, the bigger is on bottom.
   61 62 63 80   │ abc· │
   00 00 00 00   │ ···· │
   00 00 00 00   │ ···· │
   00 00 00 00   │ ···· │
   00 00 00 00   │ ···· │
   00 00 00 00   │ ···· │
   00 00 00 00   │ ···· │
   00 00 00 00   │ ···· │
   00 00 00 00   │ ···· │
   00 00 00 00   │ ···· │
   00 00 00 00   │ ···· │
   00 00 00 00   │ ···· │
   00 00 00 00   │ ···· │
   00 00 00 00   │ ···· │
   00 00 00 00   │ ···· │
   00 00 00 18   │ ···· │

Strings remain unaffected by endianness because it only affects multibyte values. However, the specification then continues to claim that initial hash values have to be defined (their values are given in the specs), however it fails to convey whether they are in little or big endian - this is crucial and it has grave consequences on the results:
H0 = 0x6a09e667
H1 = 0xbb67ae85
H2 = 0x3c6ef372
H3 = 0xa54ff53a
H4 = 0x510e527f
H5 = 0x9b05688c
H6 = 0x1f83d9ab
H7 = 0x5be0cd19

Then the problems begin. There is a message schedule (uint32_t array[64]) that makes 64 32-bit words out of 16 32-bit words in a 512bit block. Its definition is in the specification in the section 6.2.2. It is as follows:
For the first 16 words of the schedule, they are just copied from the original message. Here comes the first question - if they are to be interpreted as 32bit numbers, how should the first line of the original message be saved in the schedule?
Should it be 0x61626380 or 0x80636261? Those are very different numbers.
After the first 16 are done, the next 48 are then created (the operations are specified in 4.1.2 section of the document):
for (i = 16; i <= 63; i++) {
    uint32_t s1 = (rightRotate(W[i-2], 17)) ^ (rightRotate(W[i-2], 19)) ^ (W[i-2] >> 10);
    uint32_t s0 = (rightRotate(W[i-15], 7)) ^ (rightRotate(W[i-15], 18)) ^ (W[i-15] >> 3);
    uint32_t final = (s1 + W[i-7] + s0 + W[i-16]);
    W[i] = final;
}

The site https://sha256algorithm.com/ allows you to step this algorithm. Once again, it fails to provide details when it comes to endianness. In this website, for example, w[16] should be 01100001011000100110001110000000. It is the same as the first line of the block. 0x61626380. My code does that as well but the value is shown in my debugger as 0x80636261 in both w[0] and w[16]. w[17] should be 00000000000011110000000000000000. 0x00FF0000. My code, however, produces the following value: 00 0f 06 00. This is where the issue lies - the endianness creates problems during the generation of the word schedule, as even summing the values will be different according to endianness of its operands.
My question is this:
What is the correct approach to handling the values? What is supposed to be in big endian, what is supposed to be in little endian, how is a line of chars supposed to be transformed into a 32bit int when the order is not set?
Below, I will provide screenshots. First one shows how W[0] to W[17] are saved in my memory, the second shows how the W[17] part should be calculated according to the website.


My rotation is defined as follows:
uint32_t rightRotate(uint32_t value, unsigned int count) {
    return (value >> count) | (value << (32 - count));
}


Re “it fails to convey whether they are in little or big endian”: Page 7, clause 3.1, item 2: “… Throughout this specification, the “big-endian” convention is used when expressing both 32- and 64-bit words, so that within each word, the most significant bit is stored in the left-most bit position.”

@EricPostpischil The problem is that the input doesn't consist of numbers, so there is no "most significant bit". However, one should remember that loading them as little endian numbers reverses the bytes. In the calculations on registers after loading we always calculate in big endian (shift left multiplies by 2 on both little and big endian machines).

There is no ambiguity. As well as item 2 mentioned by Eric, there are also items 3 and 4 immediately after that further clarify.

@PresidentJamesK.Polk Not saying that there is, but Eric's quote doesn't entirely address the issue raised and I'm pretty sure that these kind of definitions can be misunderstood. Heck, the creators of the Skein hash made errors with regards to endianness while they wrote the specs. I send them my own results so that they could compare (obviously they were a bit skittish with regards to sending an update to the competition and having that update being incorrect as well) .

Yes, after reading Maarten's comment and thinking about it, I'll agree that it's not as straightforward. The NIST spec is not byte-oriented, it takes bits as input, pads the last block to be a multiple of 512 bits, and then breaks these bits into "words". The ambiguity is mostly resolved by the "abc" example in section 5.1.2.  Endianness must be taken into account. One way is to only do things as words, when receiving bytes inputs shift them into words starting at W[0]. When returning the answer as a byte array, reverse the process, shifting bytes out starting at H[0].

There are only two situations in which a typical SHA-2 implementation will need to convert data between bytes and larger words.  Those are when converting the message bytes into message words and when converting the state words into the hash output.  In both cases, the data is converted in big-endian format.
Thus, for the message "abc", the first unexpanded message word is 0x61626380 (with padding) and the rest are 0.  The first state word at the end of processing is 0xba7816bf, and it is serialized as 0xba 0x78 0x16 0xbf.
What byte order the constants are in is irrelevant.  They are always 32-bit words, and a typical implementation will treat them only as 32-bit words, so they will always be treated in whatever endianness the local machine is in since they're never stored as anything but 32-bit words.
If you're on one of the more common processors these days (x86/x86-64, ARM/ARM64, or RISC-V), then those are typically little-endian processors, and thus your 32-bit quantities will be little-endian when stored in memory.  This typically doesn't matter unless you're using a debugger that dumps this data in byte form, in which case it looks backwards.  If you dump data by using something like printf("%08x", state[0]) or by putting your debugger in a 32-bit mode, then you'll get a properly formatted 32-bit output and you won't have to think about how your processor stores bytes.  I don't use a debugger, personally, so this doesn't affect me in any way, but it's a thing to watch out for since you do.
All of this also applies to 64-bit words for SHA-512 and algorithms derived from it.  Most other cryptographic hash functions operate similarly, except that some of them (e.g., BLAKE2) are little-endian instead.

This should mean that you need to reverse the bytes after loading it correct? On a little endian machine the bytes in the word are stored from right to left. If you'd read abc and it comes out as 0x80636261 they the values must be reversed.

Most CPUs have a byte-swap instruction, so when you load the 32-bit quantity, you need to execute that instruction on a little-endian machine.  Normally, if you write the load as a series of 4 byte loads and a shift, the peephole optimizer does that for you.  Or you can use something like Rust's native conversion functionality.
